# HTML select tag that dictates next select option

Tags: html, css, tags

Guys i wanna know if there is a way for this:

If the first question for example in select tag is "brand of car". then you select for example "toyota". The next select option for the next option are the list of cars for toyota like "camry, fortuner, etc." and if on the first selection you choose "honda" the next select option will have "civic, crz, crv etc.".

so basically the next select tag switches option depending on the first option selected. and the biggest question is if the code is for HTML only not with CSS. Thank you in advance for your reply :)

Comment: HTML only is impossible. Define onselect on the first select and then you can either fill options to the second select using AJAX (XHR), or preload all of them and just show the appropriate one + hide the others. The first one is better, the second one is without AJAX.

Comment: This is actually done with javascript, because you want to dynamically change the next selection options that appear on the page.  It is better if you try to do it your self and then only ask if you have a problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Some JavaScript to start with - Each time the select box changes it matches the selected value with the values in the "model" object and displays the results in the model select box.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frippa/WH56f/)

```
<select id="makes">
    <option value="NULL">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
    <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
</select>




<select id="model">
</select>



$(function(){
    $('#makes').change(function(){
       var make = $(this).val();
       var model = {
           Honda:{1:"Civic", 2:"Accord"},
           Toyota:{1:"Supra",2:"Yaris"}
       };


       if(model.hasOwnProperty(make)){
           $('#model').html('');

           $.each(model[make], function(i, val) {
               $('#model')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",val)
                    .text(val)); 
           });
       }
   }); 
});
```